Input within Custom Paper Component in MUI AutoComplete does not take focus
Instead of showing selected items we render the count of selected items. We have been asked to add an input field to the top of the popup so users can filter items. The following picture depicts what we need to do.

Problem:
You cannot click in the input field!
Custom Paper Component:
const SearchForm = (props) => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const searchTextRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  return (
    <Paper style={{ borderRadius: 0 }} 
        onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
    >
      <Box sx={{ p: 1 }}>
        <TextField
          size="small"          
          placeholder="Type to search..."
          fullWidth
          value={searchText}
          inputRef={searchTextRef}
          slotProps={{
            input: {
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position={"start"}>
                  <OdysseyIcon name={"search"} size={"md"} color={"#bbbcbd"} />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position={"end"}>
                  <OdysseyButton
                    color={"secondary"}
                    variant={"minimal"}
                    iconName={"clear"}
                    size={"xs"}
                    disabled={searchText === ""}
                    //   onClick={() => setSearchText("")}
                  />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            },
          }}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}        
        />
      </Box>
      {props.children}
    </Paper>
  );
};

Setting within AutoComplete component;
...
 slots={{ paper: SearchForm }}
...

Stand-alone example you can copy in sandbox or stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zd95zd?file=src%2FApp.tsx
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import { ClickAwayListener, Input, InputAdornment, Paper } from "@mui/material";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { SearchRounded } from "@mui/icons-material";

const SearchPaper = (props) => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const searchTextRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  return (
    <Paper onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox defaultChecked />}
        label="Label"
        slotProps={{
          typography: {
            onClick: (e) => e.preventDefault(),
          },
        }}
      />
      <TextField
        sx={{p:1}}
        size="small"        
        fullWidth
        autoFocus
        placeholder="Type to search..."        
        value={searchText}
        inputRef={searchTextRef}        
      />
      {props.children}
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default function Greg() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      disableCloseOnSelect
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      slots={{ paper: SearchPaper }}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { label: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { label: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { label: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { label: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { label: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { label: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
    year: 2003,
  },
  { label: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { label: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
    year: 2001,
  },
  {
    label: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
    year: 1980,
  },
  { label: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  {
    label: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",
    year: 2002,
  },
  { label: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { label: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { label: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { label: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  {
    label: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
    year: 1977,
  },
  { label: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { label: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { label: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { label: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { label: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { label: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { label: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { label: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { label: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { label: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { label: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { label: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { label: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { label: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { label: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { label: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { label: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { label: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { label: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { label: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { label: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { label: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { label: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { label: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { label: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { label: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { label: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { label: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { label: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { label: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { label: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    label:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964,
  },
  { label: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { label: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { label: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { label: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { label: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { label: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { label: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { label: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { label: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { label: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { label: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { label: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { label: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { label: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { label: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { label: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { label: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  {
    label: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
    year: 1983,
  },
  { label: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { label: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { label: "M", year: 1931 },
  { label: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { label: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { label: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { label: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { label: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { label: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { label: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  {
    label: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind",
    year: 2004,
  },
  { label: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { label: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { label: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { label: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { label: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { label: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { label: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { label: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { label: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { label: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { label: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { label: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { label: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { label: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { label: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { label: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 },
];



The Textfield is not clickable because of your <Paper onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}> handler. You need to remove that handler and then destructure/remove the inputProps.onFocus/Blur handlers from the Autocomplete's renderInput method. Once that's done you can provide your own functionality to handle the focus and blur events to suit your needs.

Thanks Steve.  When I remove the handler the popup always closes when you click into it - copied that from another example.  I've created a stackblitz here - thoughts? I've created a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zd95zd?file=src%2FApp.tsx
